Reading and manipulating a 3D stack of MRC images
The problem I am trying to solve is a three-parter.
I am trying to read a 3D stack of MRC images (not as in: Can DM script read images with the same extension (like *.mrc) from a folder?), apply a function on each image, and output the processed image, preferably in the same order as in the original stack.
Currently, I am reading in the image stack as a file stream and simply displaying it:
file_ID = OpenFileForReading(filename)
file_stream = newStreamFromFileReference(file_ID, 1)
img :=IntegerImage("Imported", 1, 0, size_x, size_y)
ImageReadImageDataFromStream(img, file_stream, 0)

First of all, is this the best way to import a image stack?
Once the stack is imported, how can I apply manipulate each image and output them?
Thanks in advance for your input.

I'm not sure I fully understand your question. In your example code above, you're reading (successfully?) one image of the stack into img and, presumably, iterate the call, giving you always the next image of the stack? But if the the above is working already, what is then the actual question? In each iteration you deal with img the way you want. I seem to be missing something.

Thank you, BmyGuest for your answer even when my question was a bit unclear. Your answer much simplified my code as well. Thank you.

To just "load" an .mrc (stack) file, you can use:
string path = "C:\\temp\\stack.mrc"
imageDocument doc = NewImageDocumentFromFile(path)
doc.ImageDocumentShow()

Or when you want just the image of it:
string path = "C:\\temp\\stack.mrc"
image img := NewImageDocumentFromFile(path).ImageDocumentGetRootImage()
img.ShowImage()

You can then iterate over the stack using the slice commands, f.e. like f.e.
string path = "C:\\temp\\stack.mrc"
image stack := NewImageDocumentFromFile(path).ImageDocumentGetRootImage()
stack.ShowImage()



number sx,sy,sz
stack.ImageGetDimensionSizes(sx,sy,sz)
image sliceMaxProfile := realImage("Maximum of slice",4,sz)
image maskStack := realImage("Masks",4,sx,sy,sz)

for( number i=0;i<sz;i++)
{
    image plane := stack.Slice2(0,0,i, 0,sx,1, 1,sy,1)  // plane is just a reference to the memory (no copy)
    // do any processing
    
    // f.e. store the maximum value of each plane in a profile
    if (0)
        sliceMaxProfile[i,0] = max(plane)   
        
    // or display the plane rotated by 20degree
    if (0){
        image rotPlane := rotate(plane, pi()/180 * 20)
        rotPlane.ImageSetName("Plane #"+i+"+ rotated")
        rotPlane.ShowImage()
    }
    
    // or create a new stack of tresholded plane
    if (0)
     maskStack.Slice2(0,0,i, 0,sx,1, 1,sy,1) = ( plane<mean(plane) ? 1 : 0 )    
}
sliceMaxProfile.ShowImage()
maskStack.ShowImage()

